# Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'mysite.asgi'

Tags: python, django

я хотел создать простенький сайт-чат, но столкнулся с проблемой: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'mysite.asgi'`. Данная проблема пропадает если убрать из `installed_apps` `daphne`, но без `daphne`, как я понимаю, будет проблема с конектом с сокетом (его не будет), как я могу решить эту проблему?

**mysite/asgi.py**

```
from .wsgi import *
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from mysite.chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

Порыскав по интернету я нашёл вот такое решение проблемы, но, к сожалению, в моём случае оно не помогло

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
django.setup()

application = get_default_application()
```

**chat/consumers.py**

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope["url_route"]["kwargs"]["room_name"]
        self.room_group_name = f"chat_{self.room_name}"
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat.message", "message": message}
        )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

**chat/routing.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

**mysite/settings.py** (с wsgi проблем нет, а вот с asgi..)

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.asgi.application'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: а сам Daphne установлен?

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov да, установлен. на всякий случай напомню, что проблема в том, что джанго почему-то не находит файл asgi (пробовал делать "mysite.mysite.asgi.application", ".asgi.application", "asgi.application" и просто "application")